# Printer Errors using java

Tags: java, printing

Is it possible to get the status of the printer whether paper jamming occurred, ink is running low (either colored or black), and running out of paper?

For example during printing operation: I am printing a document containing 50 pages but,printing operation stopped when the print job reached page 25 because of paper jamming. I want to notify the user that paper jamming occurred by either setting the paper jam status = 1 (*initially 0).

Is it possible to get this paper jam status from the printer? If yes, how by using java programming language? If no, are there any other programming language that can solve the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterStateReason.html

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: Currently I saw PrintServiceAttributeListener. Based on its definition, I think it seems to solve the problem but, I will still try to attach this to my program. :)

Comment: Thank you Mr. engineer :) That link will really help me :)